# In Visual Studio, can I deploy C# to my own Azure Virtual Machines rather than Azure Worker Roles?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-worker-roles

In many of the Visual Studio demos, you can deploy a background worker role program (like a Console app or something) to Azure. Do you know if it's possible to direct those worker role deployments to an Azure Virtual Machine I'm running instead?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use the same deploy method you have seen with Web/Worker role however you sure can deploy your application from Visual Studio to Azure VM however the medium you will choose has to configured by you. Because Windows Azure VM are mostly configured and maintained by users that's why there is no pre-built mechanism for any one to deploy application from a development machine it is all have to be configured and choose.

In your case, if you want to deploy directly from VS, you can configure web-deploy option in Azure VM (exactly same way you would to any remove VM) so you can deploy direclty. Or you can actually configure Powershell to deploy directly from Commandline as well just you would need to configure Powershell remote setting in Azure VM.

Bottom line is you would have to choose and configure your own way to deploy application from your on-premise machine and mainly because you have more ownership to the Azure VM as in any other IaaS cloud.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. If I may ask one more question- The reason the demo is compelling is because Azure/VS handles deploying to multiple instances of the worker role. I have a Virtual Machine scenario in which I will need to deploy to many Azure Virtual Machines. Is there an easy to to use the technique you have described to deploy to many Azure Virtual Machines? Thank you!

Comment: The answer is very much user specific as you will choose whatever is easier for you and you are comfortable with. Are these many Virtual machines are multiple instances of same VM or they all are different? IF you have multiple instance to one VM, then you can enable WebDeploy in one VM which will be replicated to all. You can also use FTP based deployment to VM.

Comment: These are many versions of the same VM. It sounds like I can WebDeploy to one and Azure will replicate that to all other instances of that VM? That's great news if yes. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes that will work. You just enable WebDeploy to your VM and then when you will add more instance they all will have exact same copy of the VM.

Comment: Last question- you said "when I add more instances they will have the exact copy". Does that mean VM instances that are already alive will not get the new code deploy? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. You will not be able to deploy your applications in an Azure Virtual Machine through Visual Studio. The applications which you will be able to deploy through VS are the PaaS applications (Web/Worker roles).