# Setup continous deploy from Visual Studio/TFS to a Windows Azure VM

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, azure

Is it possible to automatically deploy to a Windows Azure VM after a successful build from Visual Studio/TFS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You question is not totally clear if you are looking for a solution for Windows Azure Virtual Machines or Windows Azure Cloud Services.

**Windows Azure Virtual Machines:**
With Windows Azure Virtual Machine, you own your Virtual Machine and thats why you would need to configure any deployment mechanism you decide. The OS VHD deployed for Windows Azure could be the one you upload or the one you got for gallery, so there are no basic deployment services running unless someone configure them first. For example if you will choose Windows Server based Windows Azure Virtual Machines, then you can install Web Deployment Services in Azure VM, and then configure your VS/TFS to continious deploy it or you can setup FTP based services to deploy your app. [This SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553689/in-visual-studio-can-i-deploy-c-sharp-to-my-own-azure-virtual-machines-rather-t) talks more on this regard.

**Windows Azure Cloud Service:**
If you are looking a solution directly from VS then you can add post build scripts using Poweshell commands. This solution will not depend on TFS at all. There are a few solutions also **[described](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Automating-a-deployment-ecd7bf3b)** which are non powershell dependent as well.

Using Visual Studio and Team foundation server components you have ability to configure the combination of MsBuild and PowerShell scripts as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/12/06/automated-build-and-deployment-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-6.aspx) and [here (same as Herve)](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/).

If you are looking for a solution directly from Windows Azure TFS (Cloud Based), **[this](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/)** article includes everything needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some information about automatic deployment here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/